# Cannot break out of while loop after entering values for a matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a simple program to create matrices and perform certain operations on them. I previously wrote this program in python 2.7, and it worked fine. However, it does not seem to work for python 3.7. The user is prompted to enter in the rows and columns of the matrix, entering in values for both (float). But whenever the user enters "quit", it asks the user again to enter in the rows and columns. If anyone can tell me why it doesn't break out of the while loop "while value != quit1:" that would be appreciated.

`There also is a ValueError (cannot convert string to float: 'quit')`

whenever I type "quit" after the program as well, since the value was converted to float while typing in the values. I commented out the value = float(value) line in order to test if it would break out of the while loop. With the line uncommented it returns the `ValueError`. Thanks

```
def main():

    print("Welcome to the matrix program!")
    print("Enter the number of dimensions: ")
    m = int(input("Enter number of rows: "))
    n = int(input("Enter number of columns: "))
    matrix = []
    for i in range(m):
        matrix.append([])
        for j in range(n):
            matrix[i].append(0)
    print(matrix)
    value = 0
    quit1 = str("quit").upper
    while value != quit1:
        row_loc = int(input("Enter a row location: "))
        col_loc = int(input("Enter a column location: "))
        value = input("Enter a value for the matrix of QUIT to stop: ")
        if value != quit1:
            value = float(value)
            matrix[row_loc-1][col_loc-1] = value
        else:
            value = quit1

    print(matrix)
    choices = "What would you like to do? \n(1) APPLY \n(2) TRANSPOSE \n(3) PRINT \n(4) QUIT"
    print(choices)
    choice = int(input("Choice: "))
```

Comment: `quit1 = str("quit").upper` doesn't call the function, you just bind the function to the name, you need `()` at the end. I'm now curious whether the user could ever satisfy the test as it currently is but that's a different issue :)

Comment: @roganjosh thanks for pointing that out. I tested it after fixing the oversight and appending the () at the end of .upper, but the same issue comes up as it still asks for the rows and columns after entering "quit"

Comment: Well it will, because you converted the string to uppercase so it expects `"QUIT"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looks like your problem consists of two parts. The `ValueError` arises because `value = float("QUIT")` is being run within your if statement. However the reason it's making it into your if statement in the first place is that `quit1` is missing the `()` in the `upper` function call, AND you should probably normalise the input. Something like this should work:

```
def main():

    print("Welcome to the matrix program!")
    print("Enter the number of dimensions: ")
    m = int(input("Enter number of rows: "))
    n = int(input("Enter number of columns: "))
    matrix = []
    for i in range(m):
        matrix.append([])
        for j in range(n):
            matrix[i].append(0)
    print(matrix)
    value = 0
    quit1 = str("quit").upper()
    while value != quit1:
        row_loc = int(input("Enter a row location: "))
        col_loc = int(input("Enter a column location: "))
        value = input("Enter a value for the matrix of QUIT to stop: ")
        if value.upper() != quit1:
            value = float(value)
            matrix[row_loc-1][col_loc-1] = value
        else:
            value = quit1

    print(matrix)
    choices = "What would you like to do? \n(1) APPLY \n(2) TRANSPOSE \n(3) PRINT \n(4) QUIT"
    print(choices)
    choice = int(input("Choice: "))
```

You could also simplify the logic further by amending the same thing in the `while` statement and removing your `else`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was unaware that I had to further adjust the value to value.upper(), but it worked perfectly